# I am getting bad_alloc error in c++ program

Tags: c++, error-handling, dynamic-memory-allocation, bad-alloc, alloc

I wrote a c++ program but I am getting an error.
I am not understanding the reason why I am getting the error.
Please help me with how to fix this.

This is my code :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define endl "\n"
#define int long long
using namespace std;

void solve() {
    int n, x;
    cin >> n >> x;
    cout << n << x;
    vector <int> in(n);
    for (auto &p : in)
        cin >> p;

    vector<int> vect;
    vect = in;

    int cnt = 0;
    int l = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (vect[i] % 2 == 0) {
            while (x--) {
                vect.push_back(vect[i] / 2);
                l++;
            }
        }
        else {
            cnt = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        sum += vect[i];
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}


signed main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        solve();
    }
}
```

The input is :

```
2 1 2 12 4 2 4 6 8 2
```

This is the error which I am getting on compiling it in sublime text :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
[Finished in 4.0s]
```

Comment: `bad_alloc` is an exception, you don't get that error at compile time. It happens during execution. What input are you giving your program?

Comment: `#define endl "\n"` and `#define int long long` are not allowed in C++ if you include any standard headers.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: This is the input that I am giving:
2
1 2
12
4 2
4 6 8 2

I changed the header files still I am getting the same error.

Comment: The bug could be here: `vector <int> in(n);` you should always validate the input before using it. `n` could be a garbage value or an illegal value.

Comment: What is the reason for the error and how to fix the error? @drescherjm

Comment: I mentioned that in the edit. `n` could be a garbage value if the user entered text like "frog" instead of an integer. Or an invalid value if the user entered `-1` or something else that is negative.

Comment: `#define int long long` -- There is no need for this horrific stuff.  There is an `int64_t` type in C++, a meansly 4 more characters to type in to describe fully the type and the number of bits the type holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the treatment of the variable `x`. Don't ask me what the solution is but I can describe the problem.

```
        while (x--) {
            vect.push_back(vect[i] / 2);
            l++;
        }
```

The first time this loop runs `x` equals two. So two items are added to the vector and `x` takes the value `-1`.

The next time this loop runs `x` starts at `-1` and so the loop runs until you run out of memory and get a `bad_alloc` exception.

Comment: It seems likely the solution is to copy `x` before the loop and use the copy. Maybe converting the `while` loop to a `for` loop which initializes its iterating variable to `x` would be clearer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes using for loop would be better and the error was due to while(x--).

Comment: Not to mention the fact that the `while` loop increments `l`.   `l` is the upper limit for `i` in the containing loop.